# I have just started android development and when i was making this app it didnt work while debugging

Tags: java, android

This app is all about clicking a `Button` and there is a `TextBox` which changes its content when clicked.

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package com.lost.eventhandling;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Button willybutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.willybutton);
    assert willybutton != null;
    willybutton.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    TextView willytext=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.willytext);
                    willytext.setText("I DID IT ");
                }
            }
    );
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```

Now for xml code I had

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
 tools:context="com.lost.eventhandling.MainActivity"
 android:background="#71f8bd">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/willy_text"
    android:id="@+id/willytext"
    android:textColor="#e83858"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="179dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/willy_button"
    android:id="@+id/willybutton"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#764045"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Whenever I debug my application it sends a message it unfortuantely stopped.
And my android monitor gives me this red coloured text:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.lost.eventhandling, PID: 2449
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lost.eventhandling/com.lost.eventhandling.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
     at com.lost.eventhandling.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: declare your textview outside of onClick event try it..!!

Comment: @Nils: Did you read the log? `willybutton` is coming out as null.

Comment: Are you sure posted xml is `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: but button is already defined @Rohit5k2....!!

Comment: No its not activity_main.xml

Comment: You can't use other xml's view here (there are exceptions). You need to put this button in `activity_main.xml`

Comment: So we do not use content_main.xml for editing the interface?

Comment: Are you using that this xml in activity_main? One more thing `new Button.OnClickListener(){` should be `new View.OnClickListener(){`. See answer by @Ravindra_Kushwaha

Comment: 1.This xml is content_main.xml the one which i posted.
2.And it works fine once i edited the activity_main.xml and defined the widgets there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace yours `OnclickListener` code of `Button` with these lines of code:

```
 Button willybutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.willybutton);
 TextView willytext=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.willytext);

            willybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
            /////PERFORM YOURS OPERATION HERE


                }
            });
```

Comment: Why? Any explanation?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 ..Null pointer exception is occurring due the use of Button.OnClickListener()  instead of View.OnClickListener() , therefore the exception is occurring in above code..What do you think??

Comment: You are right it should be `View.onClickListener` but that is not the issue. In this case `NPE` won't occur. Error log clearly says that the method `setOnClickListener` is being applied on a null reference. OP doesn't have the button in used xml. See comments on the post.

Comment: Than you are saying that, questioner is not getting the proper id of the button therefore these exception is occurring..??

Comment: Button is not even in the xml which is being used in the activity. which is causing `findViewById` to return null.

Comment: but brother, questioner is showing that , there is  id of button inside the activity_main.xml ....But any way thanks :)

Comment: I have suggested OP to update his code as per your answer because you have a valid point to show.